# Good response to the french defense

Tags: opening, french-defense, 1.e4, rapid

I am rated 1840 rapid(10+0) chess on chesscom and 1500 semi rapid (25+5) OTB.
I am preparing for a tournament and I want a suggestion regarding an approach to the french defense.
I tried playing the advanced variation but I got tired of it...

My strengths are tactics and I navigate dynamic positions very well.

I just want a few suggestions from people stronger than me or around my level.

Please don't suggest the exchange :D

Comment: similar thread https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/42952/best-way-to-play-against-the-french

Comment: I honestly wanted something more in depth…

Comment: Okay, hear me out... I used to play the exchange variation with Nc3 Nf6 Bg5 Be6 Qd2 Nbd7 0-0-0 to try to get a bit of imbalance and maybe with some luck get a kingside attack going if your opponent is slow. Against c6 after Nc3 I would play Bf4 then Qd2, and against anything else usually Nf3 first then Bf4 Qd2.

Comment: Btw advanced french is good. If you want dynamic you can try the Bd3 lines with the pawn sac on D4.

Comment: https://youtu.be/QZ1lBE-ONY4?si=oxTDzN8y9WnPAbr0 if u are interested

Comment: @cmgchess thank you, I will check it out!!